# Explicit conversion vs Implicit using reference with virtual functions

Tags: c++, reference, polymorphism, type-conversion

I do know a bit of polymorphism but I'm a bit lost in here, on the implicit conversion from `B` to `A` the method from `B` is called but with explicit the method from `A` is called, which makes sense, but it only works this way in case the methods are virtual, otherwise in both cases `ShowA` is input (the method from class `A` is called).

```
class A
{
public:
    A(){};
    ~A(){}
public:
    int n;
      virtual void Show(){ cout << "ShowA" << endl;  };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    B(){};
    ~B(){}
     virtual void Show() { cout << "ShowB" << endl; }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    B b;
    A& a = b; //ShowB
    A& a = (A)b; //ShowA
    a.Show();

    //Extra:
    A& extra = extra;

    return 0;
}
```

In addition is there a reason why `A& extra = extra` isn't forbidden, or simply because there is little importance to forbidden senseless things?

Comment: So... what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
A& a = (A)b;
```

This creates a temporary object of type `A`, copying the base-class part of `b`. It then tries to take a reference to this temporary.

Luckily, the C++ language doesn't allow you to take a (non-constant) reference to a temporary, preventing you from making this kind of mistake by accident.

Unluckily, your compiler provides a "language extension" that does allow you to do that, so if you must use that compiler then you'll need to be more careful.

In general, avoid C-style casts like the plague. When you really do need an explicit conversion, use the most restrictive C++-style cast you can, to help the compiler catch errors.

> In addition is there a reason why `A& extra = extra` isn't forbidden, or simply because there is little importance to forbidden senseless things?

There's no good reason for that to be allowed; presumably, it's not forbidden because it would be rather complicated to forbid that without forbidding legitimate declarations like `int i, &r=i;` or `void *p = &p;`